# How to get the cell.label.text values from a selected row of UITableview?

Tags: uitableview, ios6

I am new in iOS application Development and i need help on UItableview. As i am populating the table-view with json data.I am also Using Customized Tableviewcell also.
I am not getting the "huid" value of selected cell on "lbluid". The "lbluid" is showing value of "huid" according to scroll as i will scroll up it will show the "huid" value of upper most visible cell of the UITableview and if i scroll down it will show the "huid" value of last visible cell from down.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)  {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];;
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.lbl4.text = [hudid objectAtIndex:row];
    lbluid.text=cell.lbl4.text;
    return cell;
}
```

`Simpletablecell` is the customized `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may have to implement the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which is called each time a row is selected, and inside that method:

```
Simpletablecell *cell = (Simpletablecell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
lbluid.text = cell.lbl4.text;
```

The method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called the the table view is loading it's cells to be displayed, which is why you `lbluid.text` is only changing when the table view is scrolled.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Andrew Tetlaw its working for me even i got this solution before your answer but its giving warnings "incompatible pointer type initializing 'Simpletablecell *'......."

Comment: Make sure the class name is correct: `Simpletablecell` and also that it is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.  Also what's the rest of that error message? It should have some extra useful information.

Comment: Are there any risks associated with type casting the cell like this?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! NotesCell!
        let value = cell?.lblDetail.text
    }
```