# Read specific data in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Very basic iOS question. I have a table created (`m_historytable`) with four columns created in the form of subviews (**counter**, **date**, **name**, and **result**). Every time the app runs a new row is added to the top of the table. I need to read the most recent name added and pass it to a `UILabel`. I would expect the statement to be something like:

```
m_last_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ??? ];
```

My question is what I need to replace ??? with.

Comment: Where are you storing the recently added name? Is there a textfield in the table row?

Comment: I'm storing in the following way:

Comment: Every time the process runs, it inserts a new object in the table and stores the information for that record in the following way:


`APPDELEGATE.m_historytable = (HistoryData *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"HistoryData" inManagedObjectContext:APPDELEGATE.managedObjectContext];
   APPDELEGATE.m_historytable.name = g_name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be studying CoreData in more details. For getting data from your core data entries use the following code.

Create a function in your class to get context

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}
```

Now to get data from core data entities

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSMutableArray *historyDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"HistoryData"];
historyDataArray = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

once you get the array, you can choose the most recent item like this

```
NSManagedObject *object = [historyDataArray objectAtIndex:historyDataArray.count-1];
```

Then you can pass any value to a **UILabel** as follows:

```
m_last_name.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object valueForKey:@"name"] ];
```

Comment: just perfect! Many thanks for the solution provided and for your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace with some integer value as `%d` indicates the integer. Refer below sample:-

```
int count=1;
m_last_name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
```

For more refer this [example](http://programmingbulls.com/stringwithformat)

Comment: Thanks Hussain. However, my main problem is how to read the specific data I need from the table (ie. the last added name) and not so much on how to pass it afterwards to the UILabel. Thx.

Comment: Ok you need to replace with some values. You know the values to replace right??

Comment: What I don't know is how to read the value that is stored in the first row of the table for column/subview "name". Thx.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356869/how-to-get-the-cell-label-text-values-from-a-selected-row-of-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

You can pass there current date with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];`